# Python tkinter passing values to another class (which only seems to accept one value)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter GUI that will scrape certain parts of a website, to make it user-friendly, I made it so that it is in tkinter ans has different frames. the problem is, when switching between frames, I can't seem to pass additional information. This is my code (https://codeshare.io/aYXv6Y):

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("650x350")
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        self.title_font2 = tkfont.Font(family='Calibri', size=11)
        self.title_fontmainTMenu = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=16)
        self.title_fontDevices = tkfont.Font(family='Didot', size=13)
        self.title_fontT = tkfont.Font(family='Cambria', size=16)
        self.title("League of Legends Helper")
        changeChampX = 525
        changeChampY = 310

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MainMenu, ChampionSelect, ChampionRunes):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("MainMenu")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def setChampion(self, championName, championRole):
        self.championName = championName
        self.championRole = championRole


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to the Main Menu", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Champion Select",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ChampionSelect"))
        button1.pack()


class ChampionSelect(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Which Champion are you playing?", font=controller.title_fontmainTMenu)
        label.place(x=170, y=70)

        nameOfChampionE = tk.Entry(self)
        nameOfChampionE.place(x=170, y=150, width=120, height = 20)

        roleOfChampionE = tk.Entry(self)
        roleOfChampionE.place(x=170, y=250, width=120, height=20)

        page = requests.get('https://champion.gg/champion/Katarina/Middle?')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

        championData = soup.find('div', 'summoner-text')




        def whichChampion():
            championName = nameOfChampionE.get()
            championRole = roleOfChampionE.get()
            controller.setChampion(championName, championRole)
            command = controller.show_frame("ChampionRunes")

        submitName = tk.Button(self, text="Show Champion details",
                               command=lambda: whichChampion())
        submitName.place(x=170, y=185)




class ChampionRunes(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)



        button = tk.Button(self, text="Change Champion",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ChampionSelect"))
        button.place(x=525, y=310)

        # URL = f"https://champion.gg/champion/{controller.championName.capitalize()}/{controller.championRole.capitalize()}?"


        text = controller.ChampionName
        titleChamp = tk.Label(self, text=f"{text}", font=controller.title_fontmainTMenu)
        titleChamp.place(x=170, y=70)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

When trying to pass championName and championRole, i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(FILE PATH)", line 130, in <module>
    app = SampleApp()
  File "(FILE PATH)", line 34, in __init__
    frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
  File "(FILE PATH)", line 119, in __init__
    text = controller.ChampionName
  File "(FILE PATH)", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'ChampionName'
```

championName and championRole are  key pieces of information that are part of the URL for the website i am parsing so I really am not sure how else to do this. I am unfamiliar with some parts of the code and am still new to python and tkinter so please try to be as clear as possible.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `championName` is not the same as `ChampionName`.

Comment: Still, I get an error: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'championName'

Comment: Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: The error message is giving you important information. If it says the attribute doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist. Determine where and when you set the attribute, and make sure that's before you try to access the attribute.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried this code: https://codeshare.io/Gq0Jej but the main problem is how to pass championName and championRole to the other frame (ChampionRunes) It seems that I did it wrong so thats why I got an error but how can I properly pass that information to the other frame?